# reading CSV file using java is working fine in test environment but its not behaving correctly in production environment

Tags: java, csv, character-encoding, filereader

I am using CSV files which has the contents in German and french language. I am reading these files through Java using file reader. Its working fine on test environment but in production, csv file contents get changed in some symbols after reading (I can see in logs).

Comment: Welcome to SO, we are going to need a lot more detail in order to help you.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for some help.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html).  It always reads a file using the platform's default charset.

The default charset in your test environment is not the same as your default charset in your production environment.  It is exactly for this reason that you should never rely on the default charset.  I assume you know what the actual charset of the CSV file is, so specify it explicitly in your code:

```
String charset = "ISO-8859-1";
Reader csvReader = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), charset));
```

A list of all known charsets can be found [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml).  That link is also present in the documentation for the [Charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) class.

Comment: I have other concern that I cannot change the code.

Comment: could you please provide me some other configuration without changing the code?

Comment: If you have the ability to change the way the JVM is started, you can set the `file.encoding` system property to the charset of the CSV file.  This will effectively set the JVM's default charset to something other than the underlying platform's charset.  Be aware that other code may be relying that default charset, so you may end up breaking other things.